# Script / command to drop all connections / locks in Sybase SQL Anywhere 9?

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I've recently become responsible for administering an application which is essentially a front end to a Sybase SQL Anywhere 9 database, including the database itself. I'd like to use `unload table` to efficiently export the data for backup and, in the case of a few tables, ETL to get it into a reporting database / small scale data warehouse.

The problem is that the client application crashes and leaves dead connections and shared locks on a pretty regular basis, which seems to prevent `unload table` from getting the (brief) exclusive locks it needs. Currently I use Sybase Central to verify that these connections are in fact zombies and drop them myself at the end of the day / week.

Is there a command or script to drop all connections? Being able to drop everything at once after verifying that they're unneeded would be quite helpful but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Gleening through the manual http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/awg0800e/dbdaen8.pdf you might want to `dbstop` command. I think that will disconnect all users witht he `-y` option. You might also want to make sure your database and log file are synced. I got the impression that dbstop will do that, but I've never done anything like this before. I was just using my google fu

Comment: I just looked at the age of that document, it's from 2001. There might be a more updated version out there.

Comment: Thanks - looks like that may be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad to have helped then!

Answer (score 1):

Gleening through [the manual](http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/awg0800e/dbdaen8.pdf) you might want to `dbstop` command. I think that will disconnect all users witht he `-y` option. You might also want to make sure your database and log file are synced. I got the impression that dbstop will do that, but I've never done anything like this before.